# Memory Leak Windows Phone

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-phone-8, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm parsing a KML file to display a route but I ran out of memory and application terminates can somebody help me solve this problem

```
public void DisplayRoute(int i)
        {
            content = new KmlContent();
            info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/AppStudio;Component/Resources/kml", UriKind.Relative));
            data = content.DeserializeKml(info.Stream);
           if (data.Document.Placemarks[i].LineString != null)
                {
                        routeQuery = new RouteQuery();
                        routeQuery.Waypoints = content.ParseLocation(data.Document.Placemarks[i].LineString.Coordinates);
                        routeQuery.QueryAsync(); 
                        routeQuery.QueryCompleted += routeQuery_QueryCompleted;
                }
           else
           {
               return;
           }
        }

        int count = 0;
        public void routeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Route MyRoute = e.Result;
                MapRoute mappedRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
                MainMap.AddRoute(mappedRoute);
                MainMap.SetView(mappedRoute.Route.BoundingBox);
                routeQuery.Dispose();
                count++;
            }
            DisplayRoute(count);
        }
```

for the first run the route is displayed, as I navigate to the start page and then back to Map I ran out of memory

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you never release the stream you get from `Application.GetResourceStream`. Change your code to

```
using (info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/AppStudio;Component/Resources/kml", UriKind.Relative)))
{
    //rest of the code using info variable
}
```

Comment: I did that, but it didn't help I still get the same problem.

Comment: does KmlContent class by any chance implement IDisposable so you would be able to do the same with it?

Comment: Nope it disposes all connection inside itself

Comment: What I've found out is that memory usage increases after this routeQuery.QueryAsync(); function, I'm dealing with hundreds of waypoints here might that be a cause? Will splitting do the trick?